# How Can I Get Google Analytics Working in Phonegap 5.3.1

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm stuck trying to troubleshoot a problem: Google Analytics is not registering any data from my app.

I've tried several plugins to no avail. No data gets registered.

I am executing the plugin code inside the device ready function. The device ready function works properly, but no data is sent to Analytics.

Since no plugin worked, I looked for a way to do it without a plugin. A few sites suggested ways of getting Analytics to work without a plugin. Here's the code:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');




ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3', {
    'storage'       : 'none',
    'clientId'      : device.uuid
});
ga('set', {
    'appName'       : 'My App',
    'appId'         : '1123456',
    'appVersion'    : '1.3',
    'checkProtocolTask' : null
});
```

The device plugin is loaded and `alert(device.uuid);` does indeed show me a UUID for my device.

I tried this code with both web property and mobile app property, neither registers data. Many tutorials mention using a web property as a workaround. Web property requires a URL and the URL must match what you set in analytics. Using a web property as a solution may have worked in the past but it does not work for me. Is there a configuration I may have missed?

I also tested if my app was able to retrieve remote data, so I loaded an iframe in my app with no problem. So now I'm looking towards the config.xml, which uses the cordova whitelist plugin. Which explicit permissions do I need to set so that the app can send data to Google Analytics?

Here are my current settings:

```
 <access origin="*" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
 <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
 <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
 <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
 <platform name="android">
 <allow-intent href="*" />
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
 </platform>
 <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
 </platform>
```

I've been testing on a Nexus 5. I'm using phonegap 5.3.1 
Thank you so much,
- Dan

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin? works for me. Can you give it a go and check if you get any errors.

Comment: Source your plugin from `npm` and them tell me how it went.

Comment: I tried Dan Wilson's plugin. I install plugins using phonegap like this:
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

I put his plugin code in my deviceready function, but no traffic is logged on Analytics.

Comment: you can try this other plugin: https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-analytics" source="npm"/>